# Rails 4 will_paginate articles/post by tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

trying to paginate a list of articles (ideas in my case) which are on my tag show page. So I am listing all ideas that are tagged with "loremipsum". The problem is :per_page => 3 doesn't seem to take effect. All ideas show up (I have 4 for tag "loremipsum") withour error. Pagination links also show at page bottom (but page2 doesn't work).

tags_controller:

```
  def show
    @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:id])
    @ideas = @tag.ideas.all.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

In show.html.erb

```
  <% @tag.ideas.each do |idea| %>....<% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @ideas %>
```

On my idea list page pagination works just fine so no clue.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `@ideas.each` in your view rather than `@tag.ideas.each`.

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %> ... <% end %>
<%= will_paginate @ideas %>
```

That is, I believe the problem you encountered was because you were not iterating over the same collection that you applied the pagination to. Though `@ideas` will paginate, `@tag.ideas` will not.

Comment: That's actually the issue. But notice that '@ideas' and '@tag.ideas' DONT have the same contents. '@ideas' is a filtered subset of '@tag.ideas'. Speciffically a pagination of it.

Comment: @februarylnk big thanks! That was it. Now wondering how I couldn't see that?! :)

Comment: @Cristopher Thank you for the correction; you are quite right. I didn't realize that, and I certainly don't want to spread misinformation. I took that sentence out based on your comment.

Comment: @Zsolt Happy to help! Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes, whether it's somebody else's or just your own after a night of sleep. =)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
@ideas = @tag.ideas.all.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
```

with

```
@ideas = @tag.ideas.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
```

I believe you don't need that `all`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried this, its not that. :(

Comment: '@tag.ideas' is a relation, yet to be resolved. When you call .all over it you get a resolved array. will_paginate know how to work on both, though. See @februaryInk for the real solution